# using AVCaptureDevice Zoom settings

Tags: zooming, avcapturedevice

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to create an automatic zoom for my camera. However, I haven't even been getting close to figure it out. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624614-ramp
I've been attempting to use this ramp function but get an error every time I try to call the function.
I would just like the zoom to go from all the way "zoomed out" to all the way "zoomed in" in a 5 second time interval. Please help me understand what I need to do in order to create the function.

```
func autoZoom() {
  let camera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
  do { 
    try camera?.lockForConfiguration()
    camera?.videoZoomFactor = 5
    camera?.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: 1, withRate: 0.4)
  } catch { }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you were using to ramp to zoom?

Comment: @Bluewings alright I added it.

Comment: remove this line `camera?.videoZoomFactor = 5` you don't need to set video zoom factor separately when using `ramp(toVideoZoomFactor:, withRate: )`method.

Answer (score 0):

The ramp is getting set to quickly, try setting a delay or use some kind of user interaction to ramp to a new zoom level. Here is an example that proves my theory.

```
camera?.videoZoomFactor = 5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
    camera?.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: 1, withRate: 0.4)
})
```